# \\ string literal doesn't translate to \ backslash

Tags: java, string, literals, backslash

I have a string "ABC DEF" and I would like to add "\s" in between the words to make it "ABC\sDEF" for XPath matches.

```
String label = "ABC DEF";
String[] arrLabel = label.split("\\s+");
String matches = "\\s";
label=arrLabel[0];
for(int i = 1; i < arrLabel.length; i++){
    label = label + matches + arrLabel[i]; 
    System.out.println("label = " + label); 
}
```

But I keep getting label printed as `ABC\\sDEF`.
I really want it to be `ABC\sDEF`.

How should I go about doing this ?

Comment: I tried the above code and got `label = ABC\sDEF` as output. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

why not replace the space directly into \s? try this

```
String label = "ABC DEF ";
label = label.replaceAll("\\s+(?!$)", "\\\\s");
System.out.println(label);
```

if your label won't end with spaces use this instead

```
label = label.replaceAll("\\s+", "\\\\s");
```